# Naming convention for taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I had a taxonomy called: `wossom`. And I was using `taxonomy-wossom.php` as the template file that will describe a term of this taxonomy.

Now I need to change the name of the taxonomy to `wossom-balag`, so I changed the name of the template to `taxonomy-wossom-balag.php`. But the page is not working correctly.

Is the cause of the problem the fact that I am not respecting naming convention for the hierarchy?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you refresh the permalink settings?

Comment: aaaah, I forgot, thank you for noticing it to me. It works now.  It will be appreciated if you post an answer confirming that 2 words in template name doesnt affect the functionning of hierarchy.

Comment: Actually, I did that already in the answer to the question I set as duplicate. :)